# Decoding json from parse.com in Corona SDK

Tags: json, lua, parse-platform, coronasdk, lua-table

I need to decode the data received from parse.com in Corona SDK.

The example I get is below (not sure if I can get rid of "results" in the beginning before receiving in app):

```
{"results":[{"v":20,"x2":25.200001,"y2":55.250001,"y1":55.200001 ...
```

Corona says json.decode(event.response) should convert this to a lua table while I get an empty table. Can someone give me a working example? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I was trying to get results in a wrong way
This way it works:

```
local d = json.decode(event.response) 
print(d.results[1].x2)
```